# Elixir: can I use Stream.resource to progressively read a large data file?

Tags: elixir

I know how to use Stream.resource() to take the first 5 lines from
a file and place them in a list.

```
str = Stream.resource(fn -> File.open!("./data/fidap011.mtx") end,
                fn file ->
                  case IO.read(file, :line) do
                    data when is_binary(data) -> {[data], file}
                    _ -> {:halt, file}
                  end
                end,
                fn file -> File.close(file) end)
str |>  Enum.take(5)
```

But how do I then take, say, the next 5 lines from the same stream?
If I again type:

```
str |>  Enum.take(5)
```

I just get the same first 5 lines.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Eventually, I wish to read enough data from my stream to spawn some processes 
that process that data. When some of those processes complete I wish then to
read more from the same stream and thus process the next set of data, etc.
Should Stream.chunk() come into play here?
But without an example I don't seem to be able to intuit how.

**EDIT** **- several design iterations later!**

For my purposes it is easier not to use Stream.
Instead I simple create a file pointer/process using

{:ok, fp} = File.open( "data/fidap011.mtx" )

then I actually pass that fp to 30000 different spawned processes
and they have no difficulty in reading from it when ever they like.
Each of those processes changes its state by reading its new state
variables from the file.  In the module below `oR` and `vR` are two 
"router" processes that receive message - the code is part of a sparse
matrix /vector multiplier.

```
defmodule M_Cells do
 @moduledoc """
 Provides matrix related code
 Each cell process serves for that row & col
 """

 defp get_next_state( fp ) do
    case IO.read( fp, :line ) do
        data when is_binary(data) ->
            [rs,cs,vs] = String.split( data )
            r = String.to_integer(rs)
            c = String.to_integer(cs)
            v = String.to_float(vs)
            {r,c,v}
        _ -> 
            File.close( fp )
            :fail
    end
 end


 defp loop(fp, r,c,v, oR,vR) do
  # Maintains state of Matrix Cell, row, col, value 
  # receives msgs and responds
   receive do

    :start  ->  
        send vR, { :multiply, c, self() }  # get values for operands via router vR
        loop(fp, r,c,v, oR,vR)

    { :multiply, w } ->  # handle request to multiply by w and relay to router oR
        send oR, { :sum, r, v*w }
        case get_next_state( fp ) do # read line from file and fill in rcv
            {r1,c1,v1} ->
                send vR, { :multiply, c1, self() }
                loop(fp, r1,c1,v1, oR,vR)
            _ -> ## error or end of file etc
              ##IO.puts(":kill rcv: #{r},#{c},#{v}")
              Process.exit( self(), :kill )
        end
   end
 end

 # Launch each matrix cell using iteration by tail recursion
 def launch(_fp, _oR,_vR, result, 0) do
   result |> Enum.reverse # reverse is cosmetic, not substantive
 end

 def launch(fp, oR,vR, result, count) do
    #IO.inspect count
    case get_next_state( fp ) do
        {r,c,v} ->
            pid = spawn fn -> loop( fp, r,c,v, oR,vR) end
            launch( fp, oR,vR, [pid|result], count-1 )

        _ -> ## error or end of file etc, skip to count 0
            launch( fp, oR,vR, result, 0 )
    end
 end

end
```

enjoy!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As a side note, it is a common task to create a stream from a file. This has been taken care of, so you can simply use [`File.stream!/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.6.5/File.html#stream!/3) to create the stream, no need to use [`Stream.resource/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.6.5/Stream.html#resource/3) directly.

Regarding your original question: yes you are correct, [`Stream.chunk_every/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.6.5/Stream.html#chunk_every/2) is the way to go here. It will lazily split the stream into chunks of the supplied size:

```elixir
File.stream!("./data/fidap011.mtx") |> Stream.chunk_every(5) |> Enum.each(fn chunk ->
  # do something with chunk
end)
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick File.stream! is indeed a simplifier. The something I want to do with each chunk involves waiting for a message that memory/processes have freed up.  Only then do I want to read the next chunk.  Normally I would start up a loop/receive process to wait on a message - but can I effectively do that inside the fn that processes my chunk? And so delay the next read?

Comment: I am pretty sure that's how it works already, as long as the action inside the `Enum.each` is blocking until the next chunk can be read. Or am I getting this wrong?

Comment: Ah i think i see what you mean now. Yes you should be able to put a receive block at the end of the loop to wait for the resource to be freed.

Comment: Hi Patrick I got my program sorted and have edited my original post to explain how/what/why - thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Issue: if you have lets say 27 elements. you chunk each 5 so at the end you will have a remainder of 2 elements that never get operated on.

Comment: @mjwrazor You should be able to use `Stream.chunk(5, 5, [])` to accomplish that. Take a look at the docs for `Stream.chunk/4` for more examples.

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across the same requirement as the author. I wanted to create a custom GenStage producer that can be used by broadway as a custom producer. I used the following solution.

```
{:ok, fp} = File.open("enormousFile.csv")
fstream = IO.stream(fp, :line)
fstream
|> Enum.take(10)
```

Another Variant I tried initially was:

```
File.stream!(opts.filename)
|> Stream.drop(offset_from_start)
|> Enum.take(10)
```

Both of them work as expected. I didn't benchmark them, but the IO.stream worked better for my use case since I didn't have to persist & increment the offset each time a Broadway consumer demanded data.

I know this is an old question, but adding this answer here in case anybody else runs into this issue.